# What is the meaning of "flood the intake and sweep to the bi-lats"?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon, solo-a-star-wars-story

In Solo: A Star Wars Story (2018), Han is piloting the Millennium Falcon with Chewbacca.

> Han: Drop the landing gear. When I tell you, **flood the intake and
>   sweep to the bi-lats**. A little something I picked up from my pal,
>   Needles, best street racer in all of Corellia. Till he crashed and
>   died, doing this.

What is the meaning of "*flood the intake and sweep to the bi-lats*"?

Comment: Bi-lats is almost certainly a reference to bilateral stabilizers, which we've heard referenced before.

Comment: And "flood the intake" could mean flooding the fuel intake, to get a sudden (likely dangerous) burst of speed.  I'd have to rewatch the scene in question to translate it to the actual maneuver they were attempting at the time, but this makes it sound like a Tokyo Drift.

Answer (score 4):

**Solo is most likely changing a fuel mixture and then restabilizing.**

[image: cross section of the millenium falcon]

Flooding the intake, would analogous to a jet engine cause a change in the 'air-fuel'<sup>1</sup> mixture of the sublight drive.

Suddenly changing the 'air-fuel' ratio of the Millenium Falcon, would, like in modern jet engines cause some [instabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine#Combustion_instabilities) and potentially stall the engine. One can assume that sweeping the bi-lats (potentially Bilateral Fuel drive stabilizers?) would compensate for this change, and allow for the sudden burst of speed.

The linked articles implies a low pressure behind the exhaust part of the drive could cause a stall, which would not be what you want. Equally, unstable 'combustion' (for lack of a better word) could also cause resonances in the engine and damage it beyond use (potentially what Needles did)

---

<sub>1. Or the spacefaring equivalent</sub>